# Add in current number of participants in a chat room

Tags: feature-request, chat

On Mobile Chat there's this nice little tab that shows the number of participants currently in the room:

[image]

Would be nice to get have something like that for web that said:

[image: mockup]

"40 Users" (and it can be linked to the [Currently in room page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/11540/charcoal-hq?id=11540&tab=general&users=current)).

Comment: Can't say that's a bad idea, though... total or active? ;p

Comment: Currently in the room.